# How to create a slug from non-English values?

Tags: python, django, slug

I have the model **Author** with fields **firstname, lastname**. I wanna add another field **'slug'**
that will contain a slug of a concatenation of the fields. However, these fields contain non-English chars and I need an English slug to create the link template **"localhost/authors/str::slug"**
How can I implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this problem you can use the `unidecode` and `slugify`.
you should install it by `pip install unidecode`

```
from unidecode import unidecode
from django.template import defaultfilters
slug = defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(input_text))
```

example:

```
import unidecode
a = unidecode.unidecode('привет')
the answer will be ('privet') #this is just an example in russian.
and after that you can apply slugify
```

Comment: Does it work with whitespaces?Like "John Streleki"

Comment: @lhor  yes but you have to apply `slugify` after you finished to use `unidecode`

Comment: yep, but it returns this "djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield-djangodbmodelsfieldscharfield"
when I try to display self.slug, 
slug = defaultfilters.slugify(unidecode(f"{firstname} {lastname}"))

Comment: @lhor create a chatroom i will help you.you are not using it the right way.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation

Comment: @lhor join this https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238690/django-language

Answer (score 0):

You can first convert the name to latin characters using `trans`.

`pip install trans`

```
from trans import trans
from django.utils.text import slugify

author_slug = slugify( trans(first_name + " " + last_name) )
```

Or if you don't mind characters like: `%20, %C3` you can use

```
from urllib.parse import quote
author_slug = slugify( quote(first_name + " " + last_name) )
```

Comment: As far as I've understood, trans'll translate my string f"{firstname} {lastname}" into English, then slugify will return a slug?

Comment: "English" characters, not english language