# Slug field does not work for Bengali language in django. How to work with slug in bengali

Tags: python, django, slug

Django slug field does not work for any other language except English. I want to work with Bengali language
here is the code

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = RichTextField(default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/post")
    url = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
        if not self.url:
            slug_str = f"{self.title}-{datetime.datetime.now()}"
            self.url = slugify(slug_str)
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: You can add your own slug field with the name CharField. Then you can do anything. Don't use the slug field in your case.

Comment: i have already answered a such question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765200/15042684 try it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass [allow_unicode=True](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.SlugField.allow_unicode) to your `SlugField` to accept unicode chars

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    url = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

Then when you generate the slug you need to [pass the same parameter to `django.utils.text.slugify`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.slugify)

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  # new
    if not self.url:
        slug_str = f"{self.title}-{datetime.datetime.now()}"
        self.url = slugify(slug_str, allow_unicode=True)
    return super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Which slugify you are using? default django.utils.text slugify or python-slugify?

Comment: @Mehady `django.utils.text.slugify`, I had linked to the documentation for that function before but have now made it more clear

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how I've done this in one of my project.

Title : স্পেনের মাদ্রিদে বাংলা প্রেসক্লাবের দ্বিবার্ষিক সম্মেলন

You can use SlugField and allow unicode but you will get the slug: সপনর-মদরদ-বল-পরসকলবর-দববরষক-সমমলন

Let's solve this issue:

## models.py

```
    slug = models.CharField(
        max_length=200,
        unique=True, blank=True, null=True, editable=True
    )
```

```
    def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = self.title.replace(" ", "-").replace(",", "")
        return super(BanglaModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Output slug: স্পেনের-মাদ্রিদে-বাংলা-প্রেসক্লাবের-দ্বিবার্ষিক-সম্মেলন

Answer (score 0):

```
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    content = RichTextField(default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="media/post")
    url = url = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True, unique=True, max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.title}"

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):  
        if not self.url:
            slug_str = f"{self.title}"
            self.url = self.title.replace(" ", "-").replace(",", "")
        return super().save(*args, **kwargs)

        if self.image:
            img = Image.open(self.image)
            output = BytesIO()
            img.convert('RGB').save(output, format='webp', maxsize=(800, 800))
            self.image = InMemoryUploadedFile(output,'ImageField', "%s.webp" %self.image.name.split('.')[0], 'media/post', output.getvalue(), None)
        super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Answers must be in English here.