# Django get_object Not found

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-queryset

On two different PCs I run same code, which contains 'get_object_or_404'

```
user = get_object_or_404(User, username = self.kwargs.get('username'))
```

On my PC it runs ok, I get 'MVidić' as value.

On other PC I get:

```
MVidi%C4%87:1 GET http://app.local/user/MVidi%C4%87 404 (Not Found)
```

Why is that? Is it some localization setting? All Django/Python files are the same on both PCs. When user is a person without diacritic simbols it works ok.

views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/user_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username = self.kwargs.get('username'))
        user_id=user.id
        return Post.objects.filter(author=user_id).order_by('-date_posted')
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

settings.py

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'hr-BA'
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/Zagreb'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

Comment: i already met the same problem in russian language.The easiest way to solve this is to avoid passing the username as parameter you can use the user pk(id) .passing the username as parameter is not a good approach because you are actually exposing a useful data(the username).but if one day you really need to use it you can use `unidecode` please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69765200/15042684

Comment: I can't use pk(id) because I only have Username on my html page. Then, when I try to get it, it fails because of diacritic simbols. I will try unidecode.